# Pinch to zoom in and out in VideoView Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, zooming

I searched many times about this question.But i got only Image Zoom in and zoom out examples.I tried to modify that codes only but image zoom uses setMatrix. So how can i set that matrix in videoview. Please help me by giving a small example.I implemented code within OnTouch().

Comment: Try it like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468232/how-to-perform-zoom-in-out-on-videoview-in-android